# How can I change the db_column name of foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

How can I change db_column of Foreign Key in Django?

```py
class A(models.Model):
    it_id = models.CharField('IT ID', max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    it_id = models.ForeignKey('A', related_name='item', on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='it_id')
```

when I call objects,

```py
>>> B.objects.all().values()
<QuerySet [{'it_id_id'}:'xxx']>
```

It is 'it_id_id'....

How can I change 'it_id' from 'it_id_id'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the name of the *database* column, but with the name of the *Django* field. Django will automatically add a `…_id` suffix for `ForeignKey`s that then stores the primary key of the referenced object. It thus makes no sense that a `ForeignKey` has a name that ends with a `…_id`. For more information, see the [*`_id` suffix antipattern*](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/foreign-key-with-id-suffix.html).

You thus can change your model to:

```
class B(models.Model):
    it = models.ForeignKey(
        'A',
        related_name='item',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

If you do not want to do that, you can fetch the value for the `it_id` through an alias with:

```
from django.db.models import F

B.objects.values(it_id=F('it_id_id'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. and I have another question for Join table.

I wanna join table B with A. so I was tried to command "B.objects.select_related('it')".

but i can't get the joined table.. how can I join table B with A?

Comment: @DonyNoh: it will make a `JOIN`, the `B` objects that arise from this, will *not* make an extra query when you access `some_b.it`, since that already was retrieved by JOINing the tables. If you want to perform an inner join, you can filter with `B.objects.filter(it__isnull=False)`, and again you can use `.select_related` to effectively "preload" the related objects.